# iOS simulator crashes every time I build my app EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_i386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ios-simulator, lldb

I am developing an app and I'm almost done! However I've run into an issue where when I build my application, iOS simulator immediately crashes and Xcode gives me this:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x1032c0620:  pushq  %rbp
0x1032c0621:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x1032c0624:  pushq  %rbx
0x1032c0625:  pushq  %rax
0x1032c0626:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x1032c0629:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x1032c062c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x1032c062e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x1032c0631:  je     0x1032c064c               ;   swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 44
0x1032c0633:  movq   0x82756(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x1032c063a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x1032c063d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x1032c0640:  callq  0x1032c31ca               ; symbol stub for:   objc_msgSend
0x1032c0645:  testb  %al, %al
0x1032c0647:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x1032c064a:  je     0x1032c0653               ;   swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 51
0x1032c064c:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x1032c0650:  popq   %rbx
0x1032c0651:  popq   %rbp
0x1032c0652:  retq   
0x1032c0653:  leaq   0xcdc8(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast   failed"
0x1032c065a:  movq   %rax, 0x8ae57(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x1032c0661:  int3   
0x1032c0662:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

highlighting the last line telling me EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error with no description before it gave me the exact same issue but it told me that 'localizable string has failed to load' referring to the storyboard. Although now it doesn't tell me anything only (lldb). I was wondering if this could have something to do with the storyboard as well. Please help

Comment: Is it a problem with your code, or with the simulator?  If you don't know, you could quickly create a new project and try to build that in the simulator.

Comment: @cullub haha I was planning on doing exactly that if nobody could help me find a solution, and there isn't anything wrong with my code because every thing was finished last night and when I built it no errors were shown, but today something is going on. I even rebooted my computer but no dice.

Comment: Did you make changes to your code since you built it successfully?  You could try rolling back changes...

Comment: @cullub nope no changes, no nothing I even tried removing the work I did last night and then ran it again but it still gave me the error

Comment: Huh, that's strange.  Have you tried the New Project yet?

Comment: @cullub I'm doing it right now

Comment: Awesome.  If that fails, the thing to do might be to 1) Try a different computer with xcode, of 2) Reinstall xcode on the current computer.  Keep me updated!

Comment: @cullub it works! Why is it that one wouldn't work but  the other would?

Comment: @cullub well, I got the old one to work because I found the problem, and the new one works too. So I guess I answered my own question, but thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Awesome!  Go ahead and "accept" your answer below by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was! It turns out that I changed one of the classes of one of my view objects inside my scenes (I hope I worded it well enough).

Comment: Would please mind to elaborate your answer little more?

Comment: @hagile sure! so when you go into the `Storyboard` in Xcode, each scene in the `Storyboard` needs to have a `ViewController` assigned to it. My issue was that I didn't have a `ViewController` assigned to them. Does that make sense?

Comment: Aah, got that. Thanks CoolMan. But that didn't made the trick for me.